# some CRON jobs are not executed

Tags: cron

some CRON jobs are not executed like:

crontab -e

- - - - - /usr/bin/echo "Hello"

cron is running

/var/log/syslog:

```
May  7 16:31:16 zika crontab[115379]: (brad) REPLACE (brad)
May  7 16:31:16 zika crontab[115379]: (brad) END EDIT (brad)
May  7 16:32:01 zika cron[39572]: (brad) RELOAD (crontabs/brad)
```

but other jobs are executed OK

what could be wrong?

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's not executing?

Comment: Your `echo` is likely located in `/bin` not `/usr/bin`

Comment: Where do you expect the output to go ? Look in /var/log/syslog for messages on cron execution. On my system echo is /bin/echo.

Comment: whereis echo
echo: /usr/bin/echo /usr/share/man/man1/echo.1.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jobs are executed. To see it change your cron job the next way:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/echo "hello" | logger
```

`| logger` will send your `echo` to `syslog` so you could see it. But in your case without `logger` it is actually shown in some virtual terminal you couldn't see.

`$ journalctl -f`

```
тра 08 00:47:01 ubuntu CRON[21927]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
тра 08 00:47:01 ubuntu CRON[21929]: (user1) CMD (/usr/bin/echo "hello" | logger)
тра 08 00:47:01 ubuntu user1[21931]: hello
```

From `man logger`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       logger makes entries in the system log.

       When  the optional message argument is present, it is written to the log.  If it
       is not present, and the -f option is not given either, then  standard  input  is
       logged.
```